# Make a database search and show with google charts in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, charts

I am new to DRUPAL switching from codeigniter. I have a project on drupal you can check the link here http://idcr.cprindia.org/database. Someone please suggess me how can make search + show output with maps on the given link (with proper ajax).
how to do this integration. I have an html which is using bootstrap. (i think that will create problem to existing website).

[image]

Comment: Could you please post a picture of the kind of chart you want to display?

Comment: want to add pie charts or line charts . using google api or will use the way you tell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good morning,

As far as I know, displaying a Google Chart is quite easy. You just have to add some Javascript code.

I suggest writing your own module. In this module I would create a block. First of all, you need to perform the database queries needed to gather the info you want to display. Second, you should use drupal_add_js() to invoke a function stored in a different JS file. You need to pass the chart info in the settings array.

Hope it helps.

Comment: your reply is really good . i made a module . But getting problem their too .  it is showing in my module list but not showing in block list . i made the module from the link  https://www.deeson.co.uk/labs/trigger-drupal-managed-ajax-calls-any-time-drupal-7 . hope you can help me more

Comment: Please make sure you have implemented hook_block_info() and hook_block_view(). If you post your code (or some of your code), I will be able to help you more efficiently, and you will help others facing the same problem in the future ;)

Comment: what i did you can see in this link https://www.deeson.co.uk/labs/trigger-drupal-managed-ajax-calls-any-time-drupal-7

Comment: In that example there is no reference to hook_block_info() and hook_block_view(). That is the reason why your block is not being displayed in the block list. You need to implement these hooks in order to build a custom block.

Comment: can you suggess me link so that i can make hook_block_info() and view()

Comment: Have a look at http://fourword.fourkitchens.com/article/building-custom-blocks-drupal-7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76024/discussion-between-vipul-sharma-and-bustikiller).